# Using WKTapGestureRecognizer in WKInterfaceTable row

Tags: watchkit

I'm looking to create a table in WatchKit (watchOS 4.3) that is essentially a grid view and am using a WKInterfaceTable to try to get there.  I want 2 square items per row with each triggering a segue to another interface controller.

I have the list populating and everything looks great.  However, I'm stuck on the gesture handling. I have a WKTapGestureRecognizer placed in each respective group covering the desired areas, however the connected actions never get triggered on tap.

I did a quick test using the same gesture recognizer outside of a table and it worked right away.

My question is, is it possible to use a WKTapGestureRecognizer in a WKInterfaceTable row? (I haven't been able to find anything in the docs saying this isn't possible)

Comment: I still have not been able to answer this specific question.  However, I was able to achieve what I was aiming for by using WKInteraceButton instead. It's not as flexible styling-wise as WKTapGestureRecognizer would be, but it worked by my case.